# Api Version with Different Names

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, aspnet-api-versioning

I am using asp dotnet core 3.1 for my project. Currently, I am versioning my actions by `1.0` or `2.1` as its the suggested way to do it. But I want to version my actions by, for example, `schooljob` or some other random string value. I researched a lot, some websites claims it's possible to do `1_0`instead `1.0`
but didn't say how to. Also, I don't know is it possible to change versioning to `schooljob`.

What I really want to do is for my URLs is changing them from `...someUrl/1.0/getTeachers` to `...someUrl/schooljob/getTeachers` so I can finally group them better in Swagger.

```cs
// SchoolController.cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]  //I want to change it as [ApiVersion("schooljob")]
[ApiController]
[Route("{version:apiVersion}")]
public class SchoolController : AbstractController
{
   ...

   [HttpPost("schooljob/getstudents")]
   public JsonResult GetStudents([FromBody]Student student)
   { ... }
}
```

```cs
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("schooljob", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "schooljob",
        Title = "School Job"
    });
    // c.AddSecurityDefinition... and other swagger configurations
}   
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "mainproject/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/mainproject/swagger/schooljob/swagger.json", "School Job");
        c.RoutePrefix = "mainproject/swagger";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - **no** - you cannot define an API version this way. It has a prescribed format which cannot be changed. This is important for collation, sorting, and comparison. For example, `1.0 > 1.0-beta`.

It *looks* like what you want to do is group your APIs. The default behavior is to use the formatted API version text as the *group name* of API descriptions. This is the bridge to other libraries such as Swashbuckle or NSwag for grouping. There are several ways you can change this behavior. You can change it as an API Explorer extension (a la **IApiDescriptionProvider**) or a OpenAPI/Swagger document generator extension. To get the results you want, you just need to reorder/group the results.

Most grouping is done by API version, but it is certainly possible to group by a resource or category. Since API Versioning overrides the default group name, you'll need to re-extract the original group name defined in the source attribute or use a custom attribute. You *might* be able to build it up from template convention or other metadata.

#### Example

First, you need a way to compare 2 **ApiDescription** instances the way you want:

```cs
public class MyComparer : IComparer<ApiDescription>
{
    public int Compare(ApiDescription x, ApiDescription y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            return y == null ? 0 : -1;
        }

        if (y == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        var comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        var result = comparer.Compare(x.GroupName, y.GroupName);

        // compare by group name, then api version
        return result == 0 ? x.GetApiVersion().CompareTo(y.GetApiVersion()) : result;
    }
}
```

Then, you can create a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider** which processes the discovered descriptions:

```cs
public class MyApiDescriptionProvider : IApiDescriptionProvider
{
    // important: you may need to increase the value to run later in the sequence
    public int Order => 0;

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(ApiDescriptionProviderContext context) { }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(ApiDescriptionProviderContext context)
    {
        var sorted = context.Results.ToList();

        sorted.Sort(new MyComparer());
        context.Results.Clear();

        for (var i = 0; i < sorted.Count; i++)
        {
            context.Results.Add(sorted[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, register your provider in your setup:

```cs
services.TryAddEnumerable(
  ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IApiDescriptionProvider, MyApiDescriptionProvider>() );
```

Comment: Could you give me an example how to do it with `IApiDescriptionProvider`?

Comment: Added an example. Enjoy!